# Python script on Docker printing twice while in detached mode

Tags: python, docker

I am running a simple python script that prints "Hello" every minute

**app.py**

```
import time
from croniter import croniter
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    print('Starting...')

    # Set the timezone to 'Europe/London' to account for daylight savings
    gtm = timezone('Europe/London')

    # Create a cron expression that runs every 1 minute
    cron_expr = '* * * * *'

    while True:

        # Get the current time in GMT
        now = datetime.now(gtm)

        # Get the next run time of the cron job
        next_run_time = croniter(cron_expr, now).get_next(datetime)

        # Wait until the next run time
        wait_time = (next_run_time - now).total_seconds()

        # Make sure it does not run straight away
        time.sleep(wait_time)

        # Run job at the scheduled time
        print('Hello')

main()
```

The script works well but when I run it on Docker and use its detached mode:

```
docker run -d image
```

I get "Hello" printed twice every minute

If I do

```
docker run -it image
```

It works well too and only prints once every minute

This is my **Dockfile**

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.11-slim-buster

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create and activate a virtual environment
RUN python -m venv venv
ENV PATH="/app/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN . venv/bin/activate

# Copy the requirements.txt file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .


# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application's code into the container
COPY . .

# Run the command to start the application
CMD ["python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

Comment: i cannot reproduce this issue, it is printing `Hello` exactly once every minute at exactly `mm:00`, maybe the problem is in your operating system buffering it from your screen ??

Comment: If you are trying to build a cron daemon, this is probably not a good approach - you'd want to add support for concurrency and handle crashes, so if the container restarts or an exception occurs - you should handle these cases. 

Comming back to your problem, try a "docker ps" , you may have two instances of the container running at the same time.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Did you run `docker run -d image` and got only one print per minute on the dashboard? It might be my OS but I get two prints every minute consistently

Comment: @KevinCoder only one instance when running `docker ps`. Happy to do another approach to run an unattended script that works on the background

Comment: What about "docker run -dit --rm" instead, at a glance, I don't see anything glaringly obvious why it would print twice besides either the container is restarting or the package you using is not calculating correctly (unlikely) .

Comment: Another thing - is if you don't intend to handle complex cron expressions and it's just every "x minutes" , just get the current minute and use modulus. e.g. min/1 == 0  - if it is then run the job.

Comment: @KevinCoder not really I actually intent to do the first day of every month at 10. I tried the `docker run -dit --rm` and still double printing for `Hello`

Comment: "docker run -dit --rm image" , should work - maybe "chmod +x app.py" in your docker file.

Comment: @KevinCoder it works but again double printing only for the `Hello` after the minute

Comment: Are you accidentally running multiple containers based on this?

Comment: @bugmenot123 When I look on dashboard there's only one, on the containers preview it says "Starting.." once and then after the minute prints "Hello" and after about a second it prints another "Hello" but when running `docker run -it image` it does "Hello" only once per minute

Comment: @Álvaro - also try a  `ps aux | grep "app"`, might be a second process even if you don't have multiple containers. Can't see any other reason why this would print twice. Unless there's something weird with your OS.

Comment: You do not want to do `ps aux | grep "app"` on a mac! No matter what I do, the logs prints only the "Hello"  on the while loop twice per minute one after another

Comment: `ps aux | grep "app.py"` then

Comment: @bugmenot123  Not sure what to make of this `5463   0.0  0.0 34253900    936 s000  R+    1:46pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox app.py` on docker there is no process running